# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español para la palabra en inglés "blaster"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Cuando escribo "blaster" en el traductor online, me da como traducción: "persona o cosa que explota". La palabra la escuché en una película de ciencia ficción nueva, pero no parecía hablar de armas, parecía hablar de alguien que ponía bombas.

¿Existe alguna palabra en español equivalente con el mismo significado?

Comment: ¿Tienes algún contexto en el que se deba encajar la palabra? Por ejemplo, las armas láser de Star Wars no eran "blasters" en inglés?

Comment: Si necesitas un contexto supongo que una palabra tal cual no existe. Era en una película de ciencia ficcion nueva, pero no parecia hablar de armas, parecia hablar de alguien que ponia bombas. Pero no lo puedo asegurar porque no conozco el significado tal cual de la palabra.

Comment: There was a famous personality on our TV a few years ago called Blaster Bates who was a demolition expert https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_Bates perhaps that might help provide some context.

Comment: @mdewey so "blaster" also stands for people who plants bombs?

Comment: It would not be the normal word for someone who plants bombs, no.

Comment: La traducción sería detonador.

Comment: Coincido con Charlie en que a esta pregunta le hace falta contexto. ¿Podrías dar una frase usando la palabra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Existe alguna palabra en español equivalente con el mismo significado?

No. No hay una traducción única y genérica para "blaster" por diversas razones:

- El (significado específico del) término es muy dependiente del contexto
- En contextos de ciencia ficción el término en inglés suele ser más "evocativo" que cualquier traducción, y se favorece el término en inglés (Por ejemplo, es preferible usar "Blade runner" que "corredor de/por la navaja/el filo" por su sonoridad, aceptación, etc. Aparte muchas veces las historias de ciencia ficción prefieren no dar las cosas muy "machacadas" o explicadas a los lectores, y que ellos rellenen los "huecos" de esas historias como su imaginación les de a entender)

Blaster, vendría del inglés `blast` (que para más inri puede ser un nombre o verbo)

> (noun) a destructive **wave** of highly compressed air spreading outward from an explosion. *"they were thrown backward by the blast"*
>
> (noun) a strong **gust** of wind or air. *"the icy blast hit them"*
>
> (verb) blow up or break apart (something solid) with explosives. *"quantities of solid rock had to be blasted away"*
>
> (verb)  make or cause to make a loud continuous musical or other noise. *"music blasted out at full volume"*

Por lo que dependiendo del contexto puede ser una onda expansiva, una ráfaga (de viento o de arena) o similar.

El blaster como arma aparece en el universo de Star Wars de varias maneras:

> Un bláster [también aparece como "*blaster*"] era cualquier tipo de arma a distancia que disparaba rayos de intensa energía de plasma, a menudo confundidos con láser. [...] Vienen en una variedad de tamaños y formas, incluyendo pistolas bláster, blásters pesados y rifles bláster.
>
> Fuente: [Star Wars wiki: Bláster](https://starwars.fandom.com/es/wiki/Bl%C3%A1ster)

Pese a ello, esa "variedad de tamaños y formas" no incluye bombas (que es el contexto de la pregunta), y se refiere siempre al artefacto, no a la persona que los maneja.

En otros contextos no de ciencia ficción encontramos por ejemplo la [granalladora](https://www.ecured.cu/Granalladora) (traducción de "[shot blaster](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/shot-blaster-machine-building-industry.210222/)"). El *granallado* es una técnica de limpieza usando abrasivos disparados a presión. Podemos pensar en "**flujo**" o "**chorro**" como palabras clave en este proceso, aunque de nuevo ni es una bomba ni nos referimos a quien las pone.

Resumiendo, "blast" referido a una bomba es una *onda expansiva* (en oposición a una *ráfaga* de algo). "Blaster" como nombre para el que pone las bombas (makes things "blast") es muy difícil de traducir.

Blaster, era de hecho el nombre de uno de [mis transformers favoritos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_(personaje_de_Transformers)) (se transformaba en un reproductor de casetes, aunque en el cómic nunca explicaban lo del cambio de tamaño...).

> Blaster's initial transformation is an AM/FM Stereo Cassette Player, **commonly referred to as a boombox or ghettoblaster, hence the name**
>
> [...] As a member of the Autobot communications sub-group Blaster frequently worked with its other members – *Eject*, Grand Slam, Raindance, Ramhorn, *Rewind* and Steeljaw. He is the Autobots' answer to the evil Decepticon *Soundwave*.
>
> Wikipedia: [Blaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_(Transformers))

Los nombres de estos personajes rara vez se traducían, aunque en ocasiones tenías notas del editor sobre lo que significaba el nombre en español (como nota adicional, los nombres de otros personajes en otras series sí que se traducían en la medida de lo posible. Piensa en Wolverine/Lobezo, Snake Eyes/Ojos de Serpiente... pero Storm Shadow era simplemente "sombra". Traducirlo como "sombra de la tormenta" lo mismo no quedaba tan "chulo").

En conclusión, y como nota totalmente personal y subjetiva, un personaje de cómic o cine llamado "(the) Blaster" en la versión original posiblemente mantendría el nombre original en español o se vería traducido a algo como "Detonador", para hacer referencia a que es quien produce las explosiones (decir "el explotador" tendría connotaciones completamente distintas...).

No hay traducción obvia para "aquel que produce las ráfagas u ondas expansivas".

Answer (score 3):

Dependiendo en contexto y la manera en la que estemos utilizando "blast" es cómo deberíamos traducirla al español.

Si burdamente españolizamos el verbo *blast* nos daría "blastear" así que "blaster" sería:

> Aquel que "blastea".

Ahora que ya entendimos lo que el blaster es burdamente, podemos darle una traducción mas adecuada si sabemos lo que es "blastear":

Disparo

> Disparador

Explosión

> Explotador/Detonador

Comment: Me gusta lo que inventaste.  De ahí podríamos llegar a *blasteador*.  Esto mantendría la conexión con lo original y el ambiente *Hollywood*.

Comment: "Explotador" no serviría, es otra cosa. Es una persona que saca provecho de algo, y también el abusador que usa a otra persona.